# Issue with Maven Build command with openjdk@8

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-surefire-plugin

I am following along a course and have hit a roadblock and requesting some assistance. The original POM file given by the tutor is as follows:-

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.visualpathit</groupId>
    <artifactId>vprofile</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>v2</version>
    <name>Visualpathit VProfile Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.8.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <mysql-connector.version>5.1.36</mysql-connector.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Memcached Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- RabbitMQ Dependency -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Elasticsearch Dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Transport Client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
        <plugins>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <!-- CODE COVERAGE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

on running maven install on this command I keep getting this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project vprofile: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
```

On troubleshooting and through various sources I saw that maybe I need to add the plugin into the pom file, so from the maven-surefire-plugin page, I added this code into the pom file

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        </plugin>
```

I added this just before the line that says Code Coverage

Now on running mvn install , I am getting the following error:-

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) on project vprofile: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project' && '/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java' '-javaagent:/Users/sandeepnair/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/jacoco.exec' '-jar' '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/surefire/surefirebooter11362621506741202368.jar' '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/surefire' '2022-05-11T13-02-37_317-jvmRun1' 'surefire10287701281083249864tmp' 'surefire_0620492931166679465tmp'
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 134
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project' && '/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java' '-javaagent:/Users/sandeepnair/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/jacoco.exec' '-jar' '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/surefire/surefirebooter11362621506741202368.jar' '/Users/sandeepnair/vprofile-project/target/surefire' '2022-05-11T13-02-37_317-jvmRun1' 'surefire10287701281083249864tmp' 'surefire_0620492931166679465tmp'
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
```

I navigated into the report into the surefire-reports folder and on doing cat I am seeing the following message:-

Corrupted channel by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream 'FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed'.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade jacoco to most recent version because the version  you are using is extreme old...

Comment: hey dude on doin that basically going to 0.8.8 I am getting now this error message [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project vprofile: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties

Comment: You are using extreme old stuff: `ven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-w`  (10 years old!!)...

Comment: yeah i guess this is a 2020 course. my bad. anyway

Comment: Even 2020 that was extreme old....check which version are up-to-date https://maven.apache.org/plugins/